# How to action_click delay

Tags: java, android

i have code for action_click is there anything can petrify me to solve this problem..i want to add delay on action_click

```
private void performSmsAppMessage(final AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode) {

    AccessibilityNodeInfo textNode = getNodeInfo(rootNode, waTextID);
    if (textNode == null || sendBlaster == null) return;
    Bundle textBundle = new Bundle();
    textBundle.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, sendBlaster);
    textNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, textBundle);
    AccessibilityNodeInfo buttonSend = getNodeInfo(rootNode, waSendID);

    if (buttonSend == null) return;
    buttonSend.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
    AccessibilityNodeInfo backButton = getNodeInfo(rootNode, waBackID);

    if (backButton != null) backButton.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want delay any action try this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //put you action here
    }
}, 1300); //milliseconds to delay, in this case 1.3 seconds
```

Comment: to this code buttonSend.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);